# Is it possible to add value for Related Items filed on workflow task list display form

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have created reusable workflow for **Document Set** content type.

Workflow is trigger when **Document Set** is created in Document library.

then task list display form shows the related document set in Related Items column

[image]

In **Related Items** field I'm trying to add all documnets  Name and link present inside that document set.

Is it possoble to display all documents avaliable in document set on Related Items filed which is present on Workflow Display form inside Tasks list